# Play Integrity alternative for China region

Tags: android, huawei-developers, integrity, baidu, oppo

Google provides play integrity API for app integrity protection in android applications. But, since Google services are not available in China region, then what are the alternative APIs for integrity protection for Android apps in China (Huawei, Baidu, Vivo, Xiaomi, Oppo, etc)?

After exploring a lot, I found an alternative API for Huawei which is SysIntegrity API (https://developer.huawei.com/consum...ides/dysintegritydevelopment-0000001050156331), but I want to know about the availability of similar APIs in Baidu and other providers as well.

Comment: Requesting libraries is being considered as off-topic... while being located outside of Mainland China, you'll not use the services intended for China anyway. Can only tell for Huawei AG Connect, where Mainland China is an API region which I as European cannot select or use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah I understand that I cannot use China services outside China region but as a developer I want to use those APIs while developing my app so that it is having same functionality/behaviour for all the users worldwide.